# Integrability of modified diagonalizable Jacobian

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, diagonalization, hyperbolic-equations

I have a smooth function $f$ from $\mathcal{R}^N$ to $\mathcal{R}^N$. For each $x\in \mathcal{R}^N$ the Jacobian of $f$, $J_f$, is diagonalizable as
$$
J_f(x)=S(x)\Lambda(x) {S(x)}^{-1},
$$
where the diagonal matrix valued function $\Lambda(x)$ contains the $N$ different eigenvalues of $J_f(x)$.
If, given a diagonal matrix $D$, we define the function
$$
G(x)=S(x)D\Lambda(x){S(x)}^{-1},
$$
can something be said about its integrability? Is there a function $g$ from some $U\subseteq \mathcal{R}^N$ to some $V\subseteq\mathcal{R}^N$ such that for all $x\in U$ we have $J_g(x)=G(x)$?

Any help is kindly appreciated!